# "What does the weather look like" or "what is the weather like"?

Tags: grammar

My classmate asked me "What does the weather look like". This question is very difficult for me to answer, because my English teachers used to teach us "What is the weather like".
So, which of these two is right?

> What does the weather look like?

or

> What is the weather like?

Comment: Pleasure Kitty :) Just so you know, for me to see your comment, you need to say `@tim`. You're being alerted when I comment because you wrote the question :)

Comment: see, the answers from JR and FumbleFingers are so good but I am allowed to select one only. I hope JR and FumbleFingers can do something in the system to let other users in my situation to accept more than one answers.

Comment: you can always up vote, which shows your appreciation. Accepts are only for the one, best person. But if you can't decide, just don't worry about it :) We're all here to help, not for the rep :P

Comment: What does the weather look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English often allows you to omit a word here or there in stock phrases that are common and easily understood.

Here's how I would expand the two sentences in your question:

> What does the weather look like?

would be:

> What does the weather ***forecast*** look like?

while:

> What is the weather like?

would be:

> What is the weather look like ***right now***?

Of course, more context would help determine whether or not I've made the correct assumptions. Consider these dialogs:

> *We're supposed to go to the game tonight. **What does the weather look like?***
>   They say it's supposed to be chilly and rainy.
>   *Oh, we'd better bring an extra coat and an umbrella*.

or:

> *We're supposed to go to the game tonight. **What is the weather like?***
>   Right now, it's overcast and windy.
>   *Well, we'd better bundle up, then, if it's getting cold already*.

That said, there's a chance that the first question is asking for an assessment of local weather conditions, not for a summary of the weather forecast. Like the weather, English can be hard to nail down with precision every time.

Comment: I don't think OP's question really "equates" to *What does the weather **forecast** look like?*. The forecast already "exists", so if that's what you meant you'd probably just say *What **is** the [weather] forecast?*. The usage we're looking at is more like, say, *Manchester City look [set] to win the league*, which you could paraphrase as *Manchester City look **as if they will** win the league*,

Comment: @FumbleFingers - _"Based on what you see now, what do you think the weather will be like later today?"_ That sounds like a weather forecast to me. I think you and I are pretty much saying the same thing, just in different words.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not in any meaningful sense *disagreeing* with what you're saying. It's just that idiomatically I don't think people would often say *The weather forecast looks like rain*. Either the forecast *does* predict rain, or it doesn't - which is to say the *weather* can (currently) "look like" what it will be later (i.e. - its current appearance includes signs suggesting what it will be like later), but *forecast* doesn't normally work like that (it'll still be the same forecast later, because - right or wrong - any given forecast remains unchanged once made).

Comment: @Fumble - I didn't mean to imply I would say it that way. I just thought that wording might help the learner understand the construct better.

Comment: I understand what you mean, and I don't disagree. Not that I have a very clear idea of which aspects of usage might be potentially troublesome to learners (I imagine it varies wildly according to the learner's *native* language). I was only really bothered that a learner might see this answer and suppose it really *is* "natural" to say something like *The weather **forecast** looks like rain*, using the same slightly idiomatic structure involved in *Man City look like winning the cup*.

Answer (score 6):

This usage is effectively an "idiomatic quirk" of English. We say, for example, *"It looks like rain today"*, meaning something along the lines of *"From what I can see [of the weather **right now**], I think it will probably rain later"*.

By the same token, *"What does the weather look like?"* would usually mean *"Based on what you see now, what do you think the weather will be like later today?"*.

In most cases you would actually be *with* the person you're asking, so unless you were blind it's unlikely you'd be asking what the weather is like *right now*. If you were on the telephone it's possible you could intend that second meaning, but because of the established sense given above, most people would probably add something like *"...at the moment?"* to make it clear.

Comment: Yes, good answer. To me it is asking for a prediction, of what the weather will do.

Comment: @Tim: I was a bit surprised myself when I first read this question - as a native speaker, obviously ***I*** know what people normally mean by, for example *"It looks like rain"* (i.e. - *Although it's not raining **now**, it looks like it will **later***). And I can certainly see how the usage might appear *very* odd to a learner. But what I found odd was that neither then nor now have I been able to think of any other common context where we routinely use present tense ***looks like*** in reference to a *future* condition/event, but with no future tense verb. There must be others, I'm sure.

Comment: I've got another example; "It looks like that couple will get married", "It looks like he will do well in his exams". They are all predicting based on current events.

Comment: These are the things I notice when I explain English to someone else... For example, today I noticed when you talk about multiple people doing something, it becomes non pluralised: "He cycles" vs "They cycle". In French: "il mange" vs "ils mangent" makes sense, the default is the singular.

Comment: @Tim: I think you should be careful about using *singular/plural* that way when you're talking about ***verb*** forms. So far as I know, the ***s*** appended to present tense third person singular verbs has no connection to the one distinguishing ***an apple*** from ***several apples***. Yours was an excellent edit to the question, btw. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1):

> My classmate asked me "What does the weather look like". This question
>   is very difficult for me to answer, because my English teachers used
>   to teach us "What is the weather like". So, which of these two is
>   right?
>
> ```
> What does the weather look like?
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> What is the weather like?
> ```

Your teachers gave you the more authentic question.  Still, people would understand your classmate and give him/her a useful answer.