# What's the weather like... ? The word order

Tags: word-order

> *What's the weather like in Spain today?* or
>   *What's the weather like today in Spain?*

Is the word order correct in both sentences?

Comment: Both normal. A slight difference in emphasis, that's all.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53769/what-does-the-weather-look-like-or-what-is-the-weather-like

Comment: ["The rain in Spain stays mainly on the plain."](https://findery.com/californiawilliam/notes/how-the-rain-in-spain-stays-mainly-on-the-plain)

Answer (score 1):

As Colin Fine pointed out in his comment, both constructions are valid. 
The slight difference lies in what you're emphasing—the place or the day—depending on which, either "today" can follow "in Spain"  or vice versa.

So the expected answer to " What's the weather like in Spain today?" would be

> In Spain, the weather is fine today.

(In all the countries the Spain borders on, it is still rainy)

And to the " What's the weather like today in Spain?" It would be

> Today, the weather is fine in Spain.

(Yesterday and the day before yesterday, it was rainy)